# What exactly is a connection through socket or what does the output of lsof tell us?

Tags: python, connection, sockets, lsof

I'm streaming some files from S3 to an EC2 instance to get summary data from the headers. I use `key.close(fast=True)` for all the keys I get from `boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list()` (python library to access S3), but pass around a reference to the keys so I can read parts of them, and this works. However, I sometimes get [Errno 24]: Too many open files.

When I run `lsof | grep python` I get a variety of these:

```
python    10573 ec2-user  399u     IPv4  59221       0t0    TCP ip-10-0-0-113.ec2.internal:59293->s3-1-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python    10573 ec2-user   72u     IPv4  60910       0t0    TCP ip-10-0-0-113.ec2.internal:37952->s3-1-w.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

and one of this:

```
python    10573 ec2-user   91u     sock    0,6       0t0  61105 can't identify protocol
```

Are these webservers? What do the columns mean? I will need to research more to figure out how to close these connections in python, but do I want to close these connections? Is it smarter to make and reuse one connection, or is that not feasible? I'll figure out the python side when I understand more of what is happening, this is mostly a question for what is going on.

`ulimit -a` says open files maximum is 1024, and an option is simply to raise it. However, I want to make sure I'm closing the files I ought to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these webservers? [...] do I want to close these connections?

These are indeed connections you have made, and you should properly close at least the ones marked `CLOSE_WAIT` (this needs one extra step, because of [the HTTPS connection](https://serverfault.com/a/159569)). If you're doing a lot of things involving HTTPS sites, cleaning up properly should be enough to solve this problem. The `can't identify protocol` is probably a connection that hasn't been fully set up yet (see SF question linked above or [this SO question](https://serverfault.com/q/153983)).

> Is it smarter to make and reuse one connection, or is that not feasible?

Yes, and it should be feasible. That is a programming question, though.

> What exactly is a connection through socket[?]

A socket is typically defined as `an endpoint for communication` (in [`man 2 socket`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/socket.2.html) and [`man 3 socket`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/socket.3posix.html). It depends on which particular protocol you are using.

---

> What do the columns mean?

According to [`man lsof`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsof):

```
 An  open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file,
 a character special file, an executing text  reference,  a  library,  a
 stream  or  a  network  file  (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain
 socket.)  A specific file or all the files in  a  file  system  may  be
 selected by path.
```

The default list of columns for `lsof` is:

```
$ lsof | head -1
COMMAND     PID   TID    USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
```

You seem to be missing the `TID` (or thread ID) column. `COMMAND`, `PID` and `USER` are self explanatory. `FD` is the number of the file descriptor. `399u` indicates that the fd is numbered 339 (it can be found at `/proc/10573/fd/339`) and has both read and write access (`u`).

The `TYPE` `IPv4` indicates that it is an IPv4 socket (`sock` for a socket of unknown domain).

[The `DEVICE` output](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/lsof.html) for normal files:

> The DEVICE column tells us what device we're working on. The two
>   numbers are called major and minor numbers. The list is well known and
>   documented. For instance, major number 8 stands for SCSI block device.
>   For comparison, IDE disks have a major number 3. The minor number
>   indicates one of the 15 available partitions. Thus (8,1) tell us we're
>   working on sda1.
>
> (0,16), the other interesting device listed refers to unnamed,
>   non-device mounts.
>
> For detailed list, please see:
>
> http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/device-list/devices.txt

And the list (actually at https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lanana/device-list/devices-2.6.txt) is of not much use for devices with major number `0`.

The `NAME` field, for such sockets, is:

```
[...]  the  local  and  remote  Internet addresses of a network
file; the local host name or IP  number  is  followed  by  a
colon  (':'),  the  port,  ``->'',  and  the two-part remote
address; IP addresses may be reported as numbers  or  names, [...]
```